# Time limit when building source packages at launchpad

Tags: launchpad

What is the time limit when building source packages at launchpad servers? That is, what is the time limit before the server will abort the building process.

Comment: @JacobVlijm. You probably misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

Launchpad Help did not turn up anything useful for ["timeout"](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes?action=fullsearch&titlesearch=0&value=timeout&context=180), but there is [an old question](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/105818) which mentions a build of 9 hours, so it's probably at least that much:

> 28/03/2010 - took 9 hrs
>   (https://edge.launchpad.net/~yade-users/+archive/ppa/+build/1585814),
>   although the amd64 build failed as per usual.

Note that builds can also timeout if there's no output for 150 minutes, and [this can't be changed](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/217113):

> We can't increase the timeout. If the test suite really does take more
>   than 2.5 hours, you'll need to increase the verbosity of the output so
>   the builder can see that something is still happening.